# What's the relationship between Chrome Bluetooth API's `powered` and `available`?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bluetooth, google-chrome-app

`chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState()` returns an object with the fields `powered` and `available`. What is the relationship between the two?

E.g. can a Bluetooth adapter be powered but not available? How about available but not powered?

I'm assuming the Bluetooth adapter has to be powered and available to be useable, is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bluetooth adapter can be unavailable if the device doesn't support Bluetooth or if the Bluetooth daemon is stopped for instance.

When Bluetooth adapter is `available`, user can still turn it on and off, hence the `powered` field that can be `true` and `false`.

Yes, the Bluetooth adapter has to be powered and available to be useable.

Comment: Nice answer!  (Hi Francois :))